# How to solve Hibernate error "could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table"

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I use hibernate 5.4.9.Final with MariaDB, I want to have custom ID sequence for each entity, so I used @SequenceGenerator annotation in every @Entity class.

```
@Id
@Column
@SequenceGenerator(initialValue = 10000, name = "myEntityGenerator", sequenceName = "myEntity")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="myEntityGenerator")
private Integer id;
```

When the table has already some records, it works fine, but if the table is empty, this error is throwen when I try to call session.save():

> could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table

Is there any way to prevent this when inserting into empty table via hibernate session factory? I know that I can do a normal SQL statement and insert first record, then it will work, but I want a Hibernate solution.

Comment: No, because in this topic they use @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) I use sequence generator

Comment: See the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-auto). `If the underlying database supports sequences, then a SEQUENCE generator is used.` when you use `strategy = GenerationType.AUTO`